# Visual Studio 2019 - how to manually edit .props/solution file to force c++17/c++latest standard?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

We decided to upgrade our solution, that we are able to use c++17 standard.

The solution itself has a lot of projects and I am aware how to setup this manually through the properties of each of them (Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C++ Language Standard e.g.), but this is something I want to avoid. I want to specify this for all projects through `.props` file, that each of them can be attached or via `.sln` file, is there any way how to do this globally or you really need to specify C++ standard in a separate way for every project?

*Preferably if the answer contain the tag like `<PlatformToolset Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == '16.0'">v142</PlatformToolset>` and where to put it (of course I am not interested about toolset itself but the tag specifying the c++17/c++latest standard).*

I already searched through some default imported VS .props files, but without any success...

Comment: Read up on `Directory.build.props`, it's really essential for any sensible project setup with Visual Studio.

Comment: you could diff the project file before and after the change to see what exactly changes. After that it seems to me like a job for `sed`,`awk`, or a python script if you want quickly edit it on XML level.

Comment: @Quimby That was the first thing I did, but apparently I am blind, cause now when I checked again, the git repo contains the difference which I was searching for, but maybe I forget just to save the changes before. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case somebody will search for it you need to add:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' >= '15.0'">
    <ClCompile>
      <LanguageStandard>stdcpp17</LanguageStandard>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

to the `.props` file you are using (condition check is not necessary).

In case of latest standard use `stdcpplatest` instead `stdcpp17`.